# sqlite3 on precise pangolin: installed but not found?

Tags: 12.04, sqlite

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libsqlite3-0
Suggested packages:
  sqlite3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sqlite3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsqlite3-0
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
Need to get 375 kB of archives.
After this operation, 174 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libsqlite3-0 amd
64 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 [349 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main sqlite3 amd64 3.
7.9-2ubuntu1.1 [26.8 kB]
Fetched 375 kB in 0s (413 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 59795 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libsqlite3-0 3.7.9-2ubuntu1 (using .../libsqlite3-0_3.7.9-2
ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libsqlite3-0 ...
Selecting previously unselected package sqlite3.
Unpacking sqlite3 (from .../sqlite3_3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libsqlite3-0 (3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up sqlite3 (3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
vagrant@precise64:~$ sqlite
**The program 'sqlite' is currently not installed.**  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sqlite
vagrant@precise64:~$ cd ..
vagrant@precise64:/home$ cd ..
vagrant@precise64:/$ sqlite
The program 'sqlite' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sqlite
vagrant@precise64:/$ pwd
/
vagrant@precise64:/$ cd etc
vagrant@precise64:/etc$ sqlite
The program 'sqlite' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sqlite
vagrant@precise64:/etc$ cd ..
vagrant@precise64:/$ cd var
vagrant@precise64:/var$ sqlite
The program 'sqlite' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sqlite
vagrant@precise64:/var$ find sqlite
find: `sqlite': No such file or directory
vagrant@precise64:/var$ find sqlite3
find: `sqlite3': No such file or directory
vagrant@precise64:/var$
```

wtf? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite` and `sqlite3` are two different, non-compatible versions of the same program.

`sqlite` is for SQLite databases of version 2. `sqlite3` is for SQLite databases of version 3. There are two versions because the database format changed between version 2 and version 3, and so the two formats are incompatible.

If you installed the `sqlite3` package, you need to use the `sqlite3` command. If you installed the `sqlite` package, you need to use the `sqlite` command.

On another note, binaries are installed in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, not in `/var`, which is usually for program data. You'll also want to use the `which` command, which prints the location of a command based on your `$PATH`. Running `which sqlite3` returns `/usr/bin/sqlite3`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you for your patient and complete explanation that did not flame this wandering newby.